# Upload Video to Vimeo in Objective C on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, api, oauth, vimeo

I am developing an app from which I want to upload Videos to Vimeo, Facebook and Youtube. Facebook and Youtube have pretty straightforward apis, Vimeo has a good developer documentation, but no Objective C framework. I have seen a couple of Apps which use Vimeo, so I was wondering if there is some kind of Framework out there I'm not aware of.

Comment: I'm actually going to implement this feature, so I'll post a walk-through as soon as I'm done.

Comment: @ huesforalice can u say hw u done video upload to youtube.I referred lot of sites ,But I didn't get any perfect solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK everybody. If you're still interested in how to upload a video to vimeo, here's the code. First you need to register an App with vimeo and obtain your secret and consumer key. Then you need to get the GTMOAuth framework from Google and possibly the SBJson framework. At the moment I unfortunately don't have the time to clean up the below code, but I thought this may be better than nothing for those, who need some help with vimeo. Essentially you authenticate with vimeo, get an upload ticket, upload the video with this ticket and then ad a title and some text.

The code below won't work out of the box, because there are a couple of view elements connected, but it should give you an understanding of what is happening.

```
#define VIMEO_SECRET @"1234567890" 
#define VIMEO_CONSUMER_KEY @"1234567890"
#define VIMEO_BASE_URL @"http://vimeo.com/services/auth/"

#define VIMEO_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL @"http://vimeo.com/oauth/request_token"
#define VIMEO_AUTHORIZATION_URL @"http://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?permission=write"
#define VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL @"http://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token"


#import "MMVimeoUploaderVC.h"
#import "GTMOAuthAuthentication.h"
#import "GTMOAuthSignIn.h"
#import "GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch.h"
#import "JSON.h"


@interface MMVimeoUploaderVC ()

@property (retain) GTMOAuthAuthentication *signedAuth;
@property (retain) NSString *currentTicketID;
@property (retain) NSString *currentVideoID;
@property (assign) BOOL isUploading;
@property (retain) GTMHTTPFetcher *currentFetcher;

@end

@implementation MMVimeoUploaderVC

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        first = YES;
        [GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch removeParamsFromKeychainForName:@"Vimeo"];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)stopUpload {
    if ( self.isUploading || self.currentFetcher ) {
        [self.currentFetcher stopFetching];
    }
}

- (void) setProgress:(float) progress {
    // Connect to your views here
}

#pragma mark - handle error

- (void) handleErrorWithText:(NSString *) text {

    //notify your views here

    self.currentFetcher = nil;
    self.isUploading = NO;
    self.progressBar.alpha = 0;
    self.uploadButton.alpha = 1;

}

#pragma mark - interface callbacks

//step one, authorize
- (void)startUpload {

    if ( self.signedAuth ) {
        //authentication present, start upload

    } else {
        //get vimeo authentication
        NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:VIMEO_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL];
        NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:VIMEO_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL];
        NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:VIMEO_AUTHORIZATION_URL];
        NSString *scope = @"";

        GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self vimeoAuth];

        // set the callback URL to which the site should redirect, and for which
        // the OAuth controller should look to determine when sign-in has
        // finished or been canceled
        //
        // This URL does not need to be for an actual web page
        [auth setCallback:@"http://www.....com/OAuthCallback"];

        // Display the autentication view
        GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController;
        viewController = [[[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                                    language:nil
                                                             requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                           authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                              accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                              authentication:auth
                                                              appServiceName:@"Vimeo"
                                                                    delegate:self
                                                            finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController
                                               animated:YES];
    }

}    


//step two get upload ticket
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuthAuthentication *)auth
                 error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
    } else {
        self.signedAuth = auth;
        [self startUpload];
    }
}

- (void) startUpload {
    self.isUploading = YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.upload.getQuota"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.signedAuth authorizeRequest:request];
    GTMHTTPFetcher* myFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
    [myFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                    didFinishSelector:@selector(myFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
    self.currentFetcher = myFetcher;
}

- (void) myFetcher:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher finishedWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *) error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);
    } else {

        NSString *info = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *result = [info JSONValue];

        //quota
        int quota = [[result valueForKeyPath:@"user.upload_space.max"] intValue];

        //get video file size
        NSString *path;
        path = @"local video path";
        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSDictionary *attrs = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error: NULL];
        UInt32 size = [attrs fileSize];

        if ( size > quota ) {
            [self handleErrorWithText:@"Your Vimeo account quota is exceeded."];
            return;
        }

        //lets assume we have enough quota
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.upload.getTicket&upload_method=streaming"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.signedAuth authorizeRequest:request];
        GTMHTTPFetcher* myFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
        [myFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                        didFinishSelector:@selector(myFetcher2:finishedWithData:error:)];

        self.currentFetcher = myFetcher;
    }
}

- (void) myFetcher2:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher finishedWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *) error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);
    } else {

        NSString *info = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *result = [info JSONValue];

        //fail here if neccessary TODO
        NSString *urlString = [result valueForKeyPath:@"ticket.endpoint"];
        self.currentTicketID = [result valueForKeyPath:@"ticket.id"];

        if ( [self.currentTicketID length] == 0 || [urlString length] == 0) {
            [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
            return;
        }

        //get video file
        // load the file data
        NSString *path;
        path = [MMMovieRenderer sharedRenderer].localVideoURL;

        //get video file size
        NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSDictionary *attrs = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error: NULL];
        UInt32 size = [attrs fileSize];

        //insert endpoint here
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", size] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"video/mp4" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]];

        [self.signedAuth authorizeRequest:request];
        GTMHTTPFetcher* myFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
        myFetcher.sentDataSelector = @selector(myFetcher:didSendBytes:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend:);

        [myFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                        didFinishSelector:@selector(myFetcher3:finishedWithData:error:)];

        self.currentFetcher = myFetcher;

    }
}

  - (void)myFetcher:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher
             didSendBytes:(NSInteger)bytesSent
            totalBytesSent:(NSInteger)totalBytesSent
totalBytesExpectedToSend:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToSend {
      NSLog(@"%i / %i", totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend);
      [self setProgress:(float)totalBytesSent / (float) totalBytesExpectedToSend];
      self.uploadLabel.text = @"Uploading to Vimeo...";
  }

- (void) myFetcher3:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher finishedWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *) error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
    } else {
        NSString *info = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        //finalize upload
        NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.upload.complete&ticket_id=%@&filename=%@", self.currentTicketID, @"movie.mov"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.signedAuth authorizeRequest:request];
        GTMHTTPFetcher* myFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
        [myFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                        didFinishSelector:@selector(myFetcher4:finishedWithData:error:)];

        self.currentFetcher = myFetcher;
    }
}

- (void) myFetcher4:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher finishedWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *) error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
    } else {
        //finish upload
        NSString *info = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *result = [info JSONValue];

        self.currentVideoID = [result valueForKeyPath:@"ticket.video_id"];

        if ( [self.currentVideoID length] == 0 ) {
            [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
            return;
        } 

        //set title 
        NSString *title = [MMMovieSettingsManager sharedManager].movieTitle;
        title = [title stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.setTitle&video_id=%@&title=%@", self.currentVideoID, title];

        NSLog(@"%@", requestString);

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.signedAuth authorizeRequest:request];
        GTMHTTPFetcher* myFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
        [myFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                        didFinishSelector:@selector(myFetcher5:finishedWithData:error:)];


    }
}

- (void) myFetcher5:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher finishedWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *) error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);
    } else {

        //set description 
        NSString *desc = @"Video created with ... iPhone App.";
        desc = [desc stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://vimeo.com/api/rest/v2?format=json&method=vimeo.videos.setDescription&video_id=%@&description=%@", self.currentVideoID, desc];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.signedAuth authorizeRequest:request];
        GTMHTTPFetcher* myFetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
        [myFetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                        didFinishSelector:@selector(myFetcher6:finishedWithData:error:)];

    }
}

- (void) myFetcher6:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher finishedWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *) error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [self handleErrorWithText:nil];
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);
    } else {

        //done
        //alert your views that the upload has been completed 
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self setProgress:0];
}

- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated  {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch removeParamsFromKeychainForName:@"Vimeo"];
}

#pragma mark - oauth stuff

- (GTMOAuthAuthentication *)vimeoAuth {
    NSString *myConsumerKey = VIMEO_CONSUMER_KEY;    // pre-registered with service
    NSString *myConsumerSecret = VIMEO_SECRET; // pre-assigned by service

    GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth;
    auth = [[[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                                                        consumerKey:myConsumerKey
                                                         privateKey:myConsumerSecret] autorelease];

    // setting the service name lets us inspect the auth object later to know
    // what service it is for
    auth.serviceProvider = @"Vimeo";

    return auth;
}

@end
```

Comment: waiting for the the upload access from vimeo.

Comment: video upload is success from developer account, but not from other users account!. In the vimeo developers page , it showing message as `Approved for the following accounts:
Your account`. How to make the others users to upload their video from  the applicatio.

Comment: Hello, anybody tell me the is it work now days? I want to upload video on vimeo by my mobile app written in Objective c.

Answer (score 4):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol vimeodelagate;
@interface Vimeo_uploader : NSObject<NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>

@property(weak) id<vimeodelagate> delegate;



+(id)SharedManger;
-(void)pass_data_header:(NSData *)videoData;
- (void)Give_title_to_video:(NSString *)VIdeo_id With_name:(NSString *)name ;


@end

@protocol vimeodelagate <NSObject>
-(void)vimeouploader_succes:(NSString *)link methodName:(NSString *)methodName;
-(void)vimeouploader_progress:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalByte;
-(void)vimeouploader_error:(NSError *)error methodName:(NSString *)methodName;

@end




#define  Aurtorizartion  @"bearer 123456789" // replace 123456789 with your token, bearer text will be there
#define  accept  @"application/vnd.vimeo.*+json; version=3.2"

#import "Vimeo_uploader.h"

@implementation Vimeo_uploader


+(id)SharedManger{

    static Vimeo_uploader *Vimeouploader = nil;
    @synchronized (self) {
        static dispatch_once_t oncetoken;
        dispatch_once(&oncetoken, ^{
            Vimeouploader = [[self alloc] init];
        });
    }
    return Vimeouploader;
}

-(id)init{

    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)pass_data_header:(NSData *)videoData{

    NSString *tmpUrl=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?type=streaming&redirect_url=&upgrade_to_1080=false"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:Aurtorizartion forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];//change this according to your need.
    NSError *error;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: &error];
    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (!error) {
        [self call_for_ticket:[json valueForKey:@"upload_link_secure"] complet_url:[json valueForKey:@"complete_uri"] videoData:videoData];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"RESPONSE--->%@",json);
    }


}
- (void)call_for_ticket:(NSString *)upload_url complet_url:(NSString *)complet_uri videoData:(NSData *)videoData{


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration;
    //configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5;
    //configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5;
    configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
    configuration.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
   // configuration.networkServiceType = NSURLNetworkServiceTypeBackground;
    configuration.discretionary = NO;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                                                          delegate:self
                                                     delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:upload_url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:0];
    [urlRequest setValue:Aurtorizartion forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [urlRequest setValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    NSError *error;

    NSString *str_lenth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)videoData.length];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"str_lenth":str_lenth,
                           @"Content-Type":@"video/mp4"};
    NSData *postData12 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData12];
   // [urlRequest setHTTPBody:videoData];



    // You could try use uploadTaskWithRequest fromData
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *taskUpload = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:urlRequest fromData:videoData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
        if (!error && httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
             [self call_complete_uri:complet_uri];
        } else {
            if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_error:methodName:)]){
                [self.delegate vimeouploader_error:error methodName:@"vimeo"];}
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ AND HTTPREST ERROR : %ld", error, (long)httpResp.statusCode);
        }
    }];
    [taskUpload resume];


}
-(void)call_complete_uri:(NSString *)complettion_url{


    NSString *str_url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.vimeo.com%@",complettion_url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str_url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
    [request setValue:Aurtorizartion forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    //change this according to your need.

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
           if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 201) {
               NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[httpResponse allHeaderFields]];
               if (dict) {
                   if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_succes:methodName:)]){
                     //  [self.delegate vimeouploader_succes:[dict valueForKey:@"Location"] methodName:@"vimeo"];
                       NSLog(@"sucesses");

                       NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title"];
                       [self Give_title_to_video:[dict valueForKey:@"Location"] With_name:str];



                   }else{
                       if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_error:methodName:)]){
                           [self.delegate vimeouploader_error:error methodName:@"vimeo"];}
                   }
               }
           }else{
               //9
               if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_error:methodName:)]){
                   [self.delegate vimeouploader_error:error methodName:@"vimeo"];}
               NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
           }
    }];

}
- (void)Give_title_to_video:(NSString *)VIdeo_id With_name:(NSString *)name {

    NSString *tmpUrl=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"https://api.vimeo.com%@",VIdeo_id];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tmpUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PATCH"];
    [request setValue:Aurtorizartion forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [request setValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];//change this according to your need.
    NSError *error;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: &error];
    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
     NSString *str_description =  @"description";
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"name":name,
                           @"description":str_description,
                           @"review_link":@"false"
                           };

    NSData *postData12 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData12];

    if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"RESPONSE--->%@",json);

         [self.delegate vimeouploader_succes:[json valueForKey:@"link"] methodName:@"vimeo"];
    }else{
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_error:methodName:)]){
            [self.delegate vimeouploader_error:error methodName:@"vimeo"];}
        //NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Give_title_to_video_error--->%@",error);
    }


}
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {

    NSLog(@"didSendBodyData: %lld, totalBytesSent: %lld, totalBytesExpectedToSend: %lld", bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend);
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(vimeouploader_progress:totalBytesExpectedToSend:)]){
        [self.delegate vimeouploader_progress:totalBytesSent totalBytesExpectedToSend:totalBytesExpectedToSend];}
}



- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Task: %@ upload complete", task);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Task: %@ upload with error: %@", task, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Hi Mahesh, is it works now? Please help me.I want to upload video by my mobile app written in objective c. Please let me know.

Comment: can you provide me the code? I stuck since 7 days. I have implement this code but it returns unauthorization token.

#define  Aurtorizartion  @"bearer your token"

What should i pass here? Please let me know. it will very helpful.

Comment: my title is not updating... any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

The vimeo-Api is enough. Take a closer look to the [vimeo-upload-api](http://vimeo.com/api/docs/upload)

The interface can be used in any language which is able to send network-data. You have to create some `NSURLConnections` and you have to set the HTTP-Body like in their examples.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your repsonse. I still need to do the oauth stuff right? Is there a good framework for that available on iOS?

Comment: take a look at this: http://vimeo.com/api/docs/oauth at google I found these two sites: http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/wiki/GTMOAuthIntroduction     http://rodrigogarcia.net/2011/07/oauth-support-in-ios/

Answer (score 2):

I wrote AFNetworking Client for Vimeo API - https://github.com/m1entus/RWMViemoClient